# Is creating tasks via a for loop different to creating them individually?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

The problem i am having seems to be related to task creation.  After using a loop to populate a task array, and starting them within a separate loop, my results, although consistent, are wrong.  However, if i populate the array individually, the start each task within a loop, everything is fine. Can any one offer me some advice?

For example, this is problematic:

```
int c = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
       taskArray[i-1] = new Task(() => calculateRows(c, true));
       c = c + 2;
    }
foreach (Task t in taskArray) t.Start();
```

but this works fine:

```
taskArray[0] = new Task(() => calculateRows(1, true));
taskArray[1] = new Task(() => calculateRows(3, true));
taskArray[2] = new Task(() => calculateRows(5, true));
taskArray[3] = new Task(() => calculateRows(7, true));
foreach (Task t in taskArray) t.Start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your lambda expression captures `c` - the *variable* `c`, not its value at the time of task creation. So by the time you start the tasks, `c` will be 9. Even if you started them within the loop, there's still no guarantee that the code in the lambda expression will start to *execute* before the change to `c`.

To fix this, you can use a separate local variable for each iteration of the loop:

```
int c = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    int temp = c;
    taskArray[i-1] = new Task(() => calculateRows(temp, true));
    c = c + 2;
}
foreach (Task t in taskArray)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

Or bypass `c` entirely and compute `temp` from `i`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    int temp = i * 2 - 1;
    taskArray[i-1] = new Task(() => calculateRows(temp, true));
}
foreach (Task t in taskArray)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

Do you need these all to be separate tasks though? Could you use [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) instead? Or perhaps `Enumerable.Range` as suggested in comments:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
                      .Select(x => new Task(() => calculateRows(x * 2 - 1, true)
                      .ToArray();
foreach (Task t in tasks)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range()` and `AsParallel()` might also be useful here in avoiding capture

Comment: @Mgetz: Or `Parallel.For`, even - it really depends on what the OP is trying to do. We don't have a lot of context.

Comment: Cheers! was driving me mad... i am not using a parallel.for because i am partitioning a 2D array, i.e. x-amount of rows per task. So i am assigning the workload specifically; trying to keep the overhead as small as possible.